# How to pass jenkins parameters as array to bash script?

Tags: bash, jenkins

I want to pass in jenkins parameters as array args to my bash script.

I have tried below but no luck.

```
   stage('Foo Step') {
        steps {
            script {
                sh "chmod 755 runFooBar.sh"
                sh """
                    ./runFooBar.sh --baz="${params.BAZ[@]}" --bar="${params.BAR}" --foo="${params.FOO[@]}"
                """
            }
        }
    }
```

I am getting this error when I run above script.

```
 WorkflowScript: 48: unexpected token: @ @ line 48, column 75.
 ./runFooBar.sh  --baz="${params.BAZ[@]}" --bar
                                     ^
```

Thank you in advance.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had similar issue to resolve. 
Try to remove the '[@]' as groovy seems not to appreciate this.

In my case it looks as follows and works thus far:

```
steps {
    script {
        RECIPIENTS = '"user1@domain" "user2@domain" "user3@domain"'
        sh "./send_email.sh ${RECIPIENTS}"
    }
}
```